# Self-built Chromium - [0508/124926.422904:ERROR:icu_util.cc(240)]

Tags: arch-linux, chrome, open-source

I'm on Arch Linux and it's on my VPS too. I've just built a Chromium from the source code. The code wasn't been modified, and I only specified some flags for speeding up the process. After it got done, I downloaded it -- `out/myBuild/chrome` -- onto my local machine, ran and it threw an exception:

```
[0508/124926.422904:ERROR:icu_util.cc(240)] Invalid file descriptor to ICU data received.
```

If it was a different OS, or Linux distro of a different version, I would've understood. But Arch is a rolling distro. On both machines everything is up to date.

What's the matter? How to fix it?